# Webcam in Android emulator: "Cannot start camera" and "Result too large"

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

I have an Android 4.1.2 AVD that needs to use the camera. I tried using my webcam as a substitute in the emulator, but I get this error:

> [2012-11-16 10:35:37 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: _camera_client_query_start: Cannot start camera 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' for NV21[640x480]: Result too large

How do I fix this error?

Comment: http://www.wilsonmar.com/android_emulators.htm

Comment: http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleswhitepapers/181-common-android-virtual-device-configurations

Comment: Try to choose lower resolution for preview. Also, most webcams give rgb pixel format, while Android hw cameras return NV21 by default. Try setting preview format to RGB.

Answer (score 1):

Goto window -> AVD Manager -> select your AVD name ->click Edit button -> Abstracted LCD density click value drop down value select 160.

To enable Camera in your Android Emulator, just add following highlighted code in your AVD’s config.ini file. You can find the config.ini file under your user directory/.android folder.

File: ~/.android/config.ini

```
hw.lcd.density=160
skin.name=HVGA
skin.path=platforms\android-9\skins\HVGA
hw.cpu.arch=arm
abi.type=armeabi
vm.heapSize=24
image.sysdir.1=platforms\android-9\images\
hw.camera=yes
sdcard.size=64M
...
```

Comment: Is it just me or is this value unavailable in [my AVD edit window](http://i.imgur.com/ykCAT.png)?

Comment: I edited `config.ini` so that `hw.lcd.density=160`. Now I get *[2012-11-16 13:59:57 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: _camera_client_query_start: Cannot start camera 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' for NV21[640x480]: Result too large*.

Comment: chk this link... http://www.41post.com/3470/programming/android-retrieving-the-camera-preview-as-a-pixel-array

Comment: Goto window -> AVD Manager -> select your AVD name ->click Edit button -> Camera support value=yes

Comment: If I add the above text to my `android.ini` (replacing existing keys with your value) the emulator won't start. I don't see a *Camera support value* in my [AVD settings screen](http://i.imgur.com/ykCAT.png).

Comment: Why are we seeing different settings in the same window?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem. Just go to AVD Manager, EDIT your device.
At the SD Card section, increase the size from blank to a certain amount. I put mine 64MiB and it worked fine.

Comment: My AVD was already set to 64MB of SD card space at the time. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413943/webcam-in-android-emulator-cannot-start-camera-and-result-too-large/19037312#comment18333612_13415551).

Answer (score 0):

There is this option "EMULATED" (along with NO CAMERA and WEBCAM0) in the AVD manager advanced settings, it did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the resulting image or video is in fact, too large to be true for a smartphone or a tablet? In any case, if you need to test hardware-dependent features such as the camera, it's wise to directly do it on a device. You can't assume that the camera in your computer or webcam behaves the same as the camera in a smartphone.