# Has anybody ever got the emulator working with a webcam?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-2017, android-camera

a bit of a reverse question.... We're looking to develop apps using vs 2017 and Xamarin. However, we simply can't get the Android emulator to work with a usb webcam on a windows 10 PC. 
We've just running the emulator, no visual studio code and using the camera app on the emulator. We've tried all the different version of the OS, all have the same result... If we set the front or back camera to emulate, we see the black and white checkerboard but if we set it to webcam(0), we get a could not connect to camera error msg.

We have also tried all the suggestions in similar questions, i.e. clear the memory, increasing sdcard.size etc.

[Android studio's emulator has an error "can't connect to camera"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832637/android-studios-emulator-has-an-error-cant-connect-to-camera)

[Android Emulator unable to open/connect with real webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004794/android-emulator-unable-to-open-connect-with-real-webcam)

Nothing seems to work...and none of the above answers have a positive answer (other than use a different emulator, which we are about to try)

So my question is "has anybody ever got this to work" or we hunting for a unicorn and it just doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest, the unicorn was there the first time I connected my cheap Genius USB camera from 2007 into my Windows 8.1 PC and configured the Back Camera as Webcam(0) in the Android emulator, to test a barcode scanning app made with Cordova 7.1.0 CLI.

I would suggest you to try with Android system images from different API levels (I think I used Android 5.1 or 6.0 for my tests) and also, why not, update the Android SDK tools. (I used the old SDK tools 24 at the time). If using the standalone SDK manager instead of Android Studio (like I do) follow [these steps to update](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/) your SDK tools to version 27.

I hope this helps, anyway, you now know that the unicorn may be elusive but it can be found if you have the proper settings.